# Java get() functionality in C#

Tags: java, c#, code-conversion

I am trying to convert some Java to C# and I have a line as follows:

```
int[][] variableName = get();
```

What my question is is what does "get();" actually do?  There is no function or method in the Java code I am converting called "get()" so I am assuming "get();" simply creates an empty object of the required type, in this case, an empty int[][].  Would I be correct in this assumption or does "get()" in Java have some other meaning?

I have searched for "get()" within stackoverflow but the () are ignored and as a result I get masses of information about HTTP GET which is not what I'm after so excuse me if this is duplicated anywhere else.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it's a method declared in the calling class. Are you sure you looked correctly?

Comment: well, `get` just looks like a method call from the current class...

Comment: Or, it's an inherited method from a parent class.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? In that case, you can probably just right-click `get` and 'go to declaration' or something. Or even just hover over it with your mouse.

Comment: Check parent classes, it can be there as well. Looks like a static method.

Comment: @ChetanGole: *"Looks like a static method"* Would that that were true. A *huge* number of Java programmers choose to leave `this.` off even when dealing with instance methods and fields.

Comment: If it's not in the class or in any superclass, it might be a statically imported method from another class. There would be an `import static ...;` statement at the top of the source file in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no function or method in the Java code I am converting called "get()"

There must be, either in that class or one of its superclasses, or as a [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) although that's not very likely. *([Nice one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123896/java-get-functionality-in-c-sharp/33123969#comment54062077_33123896), [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper)!)* My guess is that you haven't checked all of the superclasses.

> ...so I am assuming "get();" simply creates an empty object of the required type, in this case, an empty int[][]. Would I be correct in this assumption or does "get()" in Java have some other meaning?

No, unlike C#, `get` is not a keyword and has no special meaning in Java. That line of code calls a method called `get` (it could just as easily be called `foo`) which is declared in the class or one of its superclasses. It may be a `static` or instance method, but it *will* be defined by the class or one of its superclasses, or as a static import.

Comment: I am using NetBeans and I'm used to using VS but using what @Dennis_E  suggested, the import is from SwingWorker.java which isn't part of the code directly (hence why I couldn't find it with a search of the code). Apparently it returns future.get() which is a FutureTask<T>, so now I have a starting point of figuring out how to implement this.  Thanks all!